# Вывод случайных чисел

Tags: php

Как вывести случайные числа в заданном диапазоне от 1 до 90, то есть числа должны выводится без повторений, и все 90, но в случайном порядке.

Answer (score 10):

Вариант 1:

```
$used = array();
while (count($used)<90){
    $rand = mt_rand(1,90);
    if (!in_array($rand,$used)) {
        $used[] = $rand;    
        echo $rand."<br />";    
    }
}
```

Вариант 2 (лучше):

```
for ($i=1;$i<=90;$i++) $arr[]=$i;
while (count($arr)>0){
    shuffle($arr);
    echo array_pop($arr)."<br />";
}
```

2-й лучше первого, т.к. в первом количество итераций цикла зависит от того, как часто mt_rand будет попадать в неиспользованное число. Поэтому если мы уже вывели 10, а случайное число еще 50 раз выдало 10, то в результате 50 лишних итераций. А во втором варианте кол-во итераций равно количеству выводимых чисел.

Вариант 3 (от [[@ikoolik](/users/5777/ikoolik)](/users/5777/ikoolik) + от меня) убран цикл в заполнении:

```
$arr = range(1,90);
shuffle($arr);
foreach ($arr as $val) echo $val."<br />";
```

Comment: Первый вариант ужасен, уберите его =)

Comment: Ужасен - не ужасен, это не важно. Главное работает =) О том, чем он плох я написал, потому использовать его или нет - это уже дело хозяйское. )

Comment: еще можно во втором варианте вместо цикла while использовать

shuffle($arr);

foreach($arr as $num) {

  echo $num;

}

так мы сможем и в дальнейшем использовать наш массив.

подскажите, как можно подсветить код в комментарии?

Comment: В вашем варианте числа будут повторятся, что по заданию недопустимо.

>подскажите, как можно подсветить код в комментарии?

Перед каждой строкой 4 пробела